# Who last modified a mailbox Exchange 2010 (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm looking to retrieve a list of ALL user mailboxes and show who last modified the mailbox in question - at the moment I've got my basic components in the form of:

```
$mailbox | % {Search-AdminAuditLog | Where-Object {ObjectModified -eq $_.identity} | Select-Object -First 1 -Property CmdLetName,Caller,RunDate | Out-file "C:\tmp\$_.mailbox"}
```

where $mailbox contains a list of mailboxes I want to process:

```
$mailbox = GET-MAILBOXSERVER | Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited
```

If I run (separately):

```
$mailbox  | select Identity
```

I get the expected identities, e.g.

> testdomain.local/Users/Administrator

in the format I'd expect to be able to pass to my search:

```
Search-AdminAuditLog | Where-Object {$_.ObjectModified -eq "testdomain.local/Users/Administrator"} | Select-Object -First 1 -Property CmdLetName,Caller,RunDate
```

(which, stand alone, runs just fine). So I'm unclear why, when I pipe my input from $mailbox I don't get any results at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code works for me

```
Search-AdminAuditLog | Where-Object {$_.ObjectModified -eq "My object path"} | Select-Object -First 1 -Property CmdLetName,Caller,RunDate
```

The first line you wrote that contains:

```
{$_.ObjectModified -eq $_.identity}
```

I dont think this will work because you are trying to reference properties from 2 different pipeline objects. I am pretty sure $_ represents the output of the cmdlet to the left of the last pipeline character. Unless you are searching for users that have modified themselves.

Running a few tests here I have noticed that some data is missing from my auditlogs. Only seems to go back a week or so.

Further reading shows that just calling `Search-AdminAuditLog` will return the last 1000 log entries. You might need to increase this `Search-AdminAuditLog -ResultSize 9000`

Also the code you are using is searching for users that have modified the administrator accounts mailbox. Are you sure you aren't trying to search for email accounts that the administrator has modified? because that will be:

```
Search-AdminAuditLog -ResultSize 9000 | Where-Object {$_.Caller -eq "testdomain.local/Users/Administrator"} | Select-Object -Property CmdLetName,ObjectModified,RunDate
```

Adding search parameters to `Search-AdminAuditLog` will improve the performance, For instance if you are looking for specific actions:

```
Search-AdminAuditLog -Cmdlets Add-MailboxPermission
```

Or a start and end date

```
Search-AdminAuditLog -StartDate "4/6/2015 12:00:00 AM" -EndDate 4/6/2015 11:20:00 AM"
```

**EDIT**
Can you try without running it all through the pipe line?

```
$Adminlog = Search-AdminAuditLog
Foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes)
{ $Adminlog | Where-Object {$_.ObjectModified -eq $Mailbox.Identity}}
```

I think it might be a limitation with pipeline you are basically trying to compare 2 lists

Comment: Thanks for the reply- sorry, my original question phrasing was a bit unclear - the final line does indeed work for me, the challenge I have is when I pass any paramters into the "My Object path" section. I'll update the question to add a bit further clarity! Thanks again

Comment: Check my edit, I think comparing 2 list objects using the pipeline might be asking to much.

Comment: Thanks - you're quite right- too many pipes (that'll teach me to try and keep it to a single line!) - I've restructured and stored each element in variables and processed serially rather than trying to pipe into another pipe. Thanks again for your help Nick!